# How to update window win32gui faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

How to update window win32gui faster?
I want to be able to do without thread, but when using while, the window freezes.

```
self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(
    className,
    title,
    style,
    win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
    win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
    300,
    300,
    0,
    0,
    self.hinst,
    None
)
self.screen=[
    [(255,0,255),(0,255,0),(0,0,0)]
]
Thread(target=self.draw).start()

def draw(self):
    try:
        while self.run:
            for y in range(len(self.screen)):
                for x in range(len(self.screen[0])):
                    win32gui.SetPixel(self.dc,x,y,win32api.RGB(*self.screen[y][x]))
     except: pass
```

Comment: I hope this is just an example.  You cannot do drawing in an infinite loop.  Not possible.  All drawing has to be done in the main thread, and you can't tie up the main thread, because your UI will go unresponsive.  This example is silly, so what are you really trying to do?

Comment: `SetPixel` is absolutely the slowest way to update the screen.  You want to blit the entire image at once.